# Count the number of labels on IOB corpus with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, conll

From my IOB corpus such as:

```
    mention Tag
170     
171 467 O
172     
173 Vincennes   B-LOCATION
174 .   O
175     
176 Confirmation    O
177 des O
178 privilèges  O
179 de  O
180 la  O
181 ville   B-ORGANISATION
182 de  I-ORGANISATION
183 Tournai I-ORGANISATION
184 1   O
185 (   O
186 cf  O
187 .   O
188 infra   O
189 ,   O
```

I try to make simple statistics like total number of annotated mentions, total by labels etc.

After loading my dataset with pandas I got this:

```py
df = pd.Series(data['Tag'].value_counts(), name="Total").to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Label', 'Total']
df
```

Output :

```
   Label        Total
0   O          438528
1               36235
2   B-LOCATION  378
3   I-LOCATION  259
4   I-PERSON    234
5   I-INSTALLATION  156
6   I-ORGANISATION  150
7   B-PERSON    144
8   B-TITLE 94
9   I-TITLE 89
10  B-ORGANISATION  68
11  B-INSTALLATION  62
12  I-EVENT 8
13  B-EVENT 2
```

First of all, How I could get a similar representation above but by regrouping the IOB prefixes such as (example):

```
Label, Total
PERSON, 300
LOCATION, 154
ORGANISATION, 67
etc.
```

and secondly how to exclude the "O" and empty strings labels from my output, I tested with `.mask()` and `.where()` on my Series but it fails.

Thank you for your leads.

Answer (score 1):

remove B-, I- parts, groupby,  sum

```
df['label'] = df.label.str[2:]
df.groupby(['label']).sum()
```

For the second part, just return data in which the length of the label column string is greater than 2

```
df.loc[df.label.str.len()>2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I think I asked my question incorrectly. With your first solution you sum the B-<TAG> and the I-<TAG> however, with the example above in IOB file : `ville de Tournai` annotated with B-ORGANISATION / I-ORGANISATION / I-ORGANISATION is equal to a one ORGANISATION entity and not 3 ORGANISATION entities. I think I should first group the tags together and then sum all. The second solution work well, thanks.